# How to disable connection to x11 window server

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, x11

I got this when I run maven project:

```
    [INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ ReportPdfSend ---
    [WARNING] 
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '208.68.90.210:5.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
        at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.(XToolkit.java:126)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
        at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getSystemMnemonicKeyMask(SwingUtilities2.java:2020)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel.initComponentDefaults(BasicLookAndFeel.java:1158)
        at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.initComponentDefaults(MetalLookAndFeel.java:431)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel.getDefaults(BasicLookAndFeel.java:148)
        at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.getDefaults(MetalLookAndFeel.java:1577)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:539)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:579)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.initializeDefaultLAF(UIManager.java:1349)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.initialize(UIManager.java:1459)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.maybeInitialize(UIManager.java:1426)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults(UIManager.java:659)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.getColor(UIManager.java:701)
        at org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart.(JFreeChart.java:261)
        at org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory.createPieChart(ChartFactory.java:338)
        at ReportPdfSend.Main.generatePieChart(Main.java:221)
        at ReportPdfSend.Main.CreatePdf(Main.java:202)
        at ReportPdfSend.Main.main(Main.java:75)
        ... 6 more
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 23.538 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-30T10:41:10-04:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 30M/289M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project ReportPdfSend: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':5.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable. -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
    [JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CanadaPostClaimReport/pom.xml to ClaimsReport/ReportPdfSend/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ReportPdfSend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
    channel stopped
    Finished: FAILURE
```

How to disable connection to X11 server. I don't need this.

Comment: Could you show us some of your code?

Comment: Try to unset the DISPLAY env variable before start the program.